# why static inline function with static variable behave so differently?

Tags: c++, linker, language-lawyer, cross-platform

I am struggling to understand why there is such a difference in behavior across compilers and platforms.

Here is an extended [example](https://github.com/ElDesalmado/static_inline_example) of http://kyungminlee.org/doc/minutiae/local_static_variable_shared_library.html.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)
project(static_inline)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(lib SHARED collect.h collect.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(lib PRIVATE BUILD_DLL)

add_executable(static_inline main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(static_inline PRIVATE lib)

enable_testing()
add_test(NAME test.static_inline
        COMMAND static_inline)
```

collect.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define STATIC
#   ifdef BUILD_DLL
#       define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define STATIC static
#   define EXPORT
#endif

// static will not compile on windows since static inline has internal linkage
EXPORT STATIC inline int collect(int x)
{
    static int sum = 0;
    sum += x;
    return sum;
}
EXPORT int get_sum();

struct EXPORT foo
{
    static inline int collect(int x)
    {
        static int sum = 0;
        sum += x;
        return sum;
    }
    int get_sum();
};
```

collect.cpp

```
#include "collect.h"

int get_sum()
{
    return collect(0);
}

int foo::get_sum()
{
    return collect(0);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "collect.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int num_from_inline_function = collect(10);
    int num_from_inline_function2 = get_sum();
    std::cout << "static inline collect: " << num_from_inline_function << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_sum: " << num_from_inline_function2 << std::endl;

    int num_from_inline_static_member_function = foo::collect(10);
    int num_from_inline_static_member_function2 = foo().get_sum();
    std::cout << "static inline foo::collect: " << num_from_inline_static_member_function << std::endl;
    std::cout << "foo::get_sum: " << num_from_inline_static_member_function2 << std::endl;

    return !(num_from_inline_static_member_function == num_from_inline_static_member_function2 &&
            num_from_inline_function == num_from_inline_static_member_function2);
}
```

### Windows output:

MinGW-w64.

```
1: Test command: C:\dev\repos\static_inline\cmake-build-release-mingw-w64\static_inline.exe
1: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
1: static inline collect: 10
1: get_sum: 0
1: static inline foo::collect: 10
1: foo::get_sum: 0
Failed
```

Clang

```
1: Test command: C:\dev\repos\static_inline\cmake-build-release-mingw-w64\static_inline.exe
1: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
1: static inline collect: 10
1: get_sum: 0
1: static inline foo::collect: 10
1: foo::get_sum: 0
Failed
```

MSVC

```
1: Test command: C:\dev\repos\static_inline\cmake-build-release-visual-studio\static_inline.exe
1: Test timeout computed to be: 10000000
1: static inline collect: 10
1: get_sum: 10
1: static inline foo::collect: 10
1: foo::get_sum: 10

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1
```

### Ubuntu

GCC and Clang give the same output

```
1: Test command: /home/travis/build/ElDesalmado/static_inline_example/build/static_inline
1: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
1: static inline collect: 10
1: get_sum: 0
1: static inline foo::collect: 10
1: foo::get_sum: 10
1/1 Test #1: test.static_inline ...............   Passed    0.00 sec
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1
```

Results look somewhat consistent only on Ubuntu. On Windows only MSVC behaves differently. More over MSVC differs not only from MinGW and Clang, but also from GCC and Clang on Ubuntu.

I suppose for MSVC on Windows the result we see is because of the linker removes duplicate symbols of inlined functions and member functions:

1. Does the standard require linker to remove duplicate symbols of inlined functions?
   For inlined functions local static members (as I remember) are guaranteed to be at the same address:

> Function-local static objects in all definitions of the same inline function (which may be implicitly inline) all refer to the same object defined in one translation unit.
> 2. What about static member inline functions with function-local static objects? Do They refer to the same object *across* translation units?

- MSVC on Windows says apparently *YES*. Is this behavior consistent across compilations?
- MinGW and Clang on Windows say *NO*
- GCC and Clang on Ubuntu say *YES*.
- **what does the standard say about this?**

3. **How ABI friendly is it to rely on a static inline functions and static inline member functions for a library or a core application that loads plugins?** For example, if a type id is stored as a function-local static object within inline static function/inline static member function?

   - I am aware, for example, that any changes to inline function body will break the ABI. But apart from that?

```
class __declspec(dllexport) counter
{
   static int get() // implicitly inline
   {
      static int current = 0;
      return current++;
   }
};
```

Comment: The C++ Standard does __not__ know dynamic libraries exist; so as soon as you use one you are into implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: (4) can't be answered (as this question stands) as it conflicts with the [language-lawyer] tag; that is dynamic libraries are not part of the Standard.

Comment: @RichardCritten C standard has `An inline definition of a function with external linkage shall not contain a definition of a modifiable object with static or thread storage duration, and shall not contain a reference to an identifier with internal linkage.` Does C++ standard say anything about that? This does not say nothing about dynamic libraries.

Comment: Have a read of __Explanation__ here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline it does not seem to have the same restriction. digging into the standard will take a few more minuets and pre or post C++17 when we got inline variables (not sure if this has an impact or not) just trying to limit scope

Comment: @RichardCritten from that explanation it seems that on Windows only MSVC complies with the standard, that is `Function-local static objects in all function definitions are shared across all translation units (they all refer to the same object defined in one translation unit)`. However on Ubuntu it is the opposite and looks to be implementation-dependent though consistent.

Comment: Try static linking as implementation defined (or not defined at all) overrides any any Standard complience,

Comment: @RichardCritten static linking is not an option for my project since it uses dynamically loaded plugins. With MSVC function-local symbols are linked and loaded from exe. Clang just silently links 2 copies of one symbol and uses one from dll. The library with static objects I use is not mine

Comment: I'm not sure what legitimate reasons you would want to write `static inline` on a free-function in a header in the first place -- this is often a user/logic error. `static` on non-member functions causes the symbol to have internal-linkage. Given that, it makes sense that `::collect()` in `main` calls a **different copy of** `::collect()` than the one in `::get_sum()`; this behavior is correct. Not sure why `foo::get_sum` would return `0` though -- that could be implementation-defined behavior due to inlining across a shared library

Comment: @Human-Compiler there's no static inline functions in the headers, only memder functions. Example with a free function was a result of misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

With `#define STATIC static`, the `::collect` that `main` calls is simply a **different** function from the one that `::get_sum` calls, so I don’t know what other behavior you expect.  This doesn’t apply to **member** functions, static or otherwise; `static` means something completely different there, and the multiple definitions of `foo` all define the same **type** with the same member functions.

Comment: Though this is true for `::collect(...)` and `::get_sum()` , this doesn't quite explain `foo::collect(...)` and `foo::get_sum()` returning different results. I suspect the latter may just be due to implementation-defined behavior through library boundaries, assuming `foo::collect(...)` was inlined into the library containing `foo::get_sum()` -- in which case `main` might not see that `foo::get_sum` was already instantiated in the library before.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: That’s just the usual Windows thing of making every variable exist separately per dynamic object (whether or not `foo::collect` is inlined).  I tend to treat that as “nonconforming” rather than “dynamic libraries aren’t standardized” simply because it shouldn’t matter so long as the linking is all done before program startup.